# How to implement currency to is-static class?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is the currency code I used to use before making it is-static

```
| currency('£')
```

This is my input field as of now without the currency -

```
<input v-bind:class="{'is-static': !foodItem.editing}" type="text" class="input" v-model="foodItem.price">
```

When I implement it myself it keeps messing it all up, any idea how to add that currency to my input, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use if else block:

```
<div v-if="!foodItem.editing">{{ foodItem.price  | currency('£') }}</div>
<div v-else>{{ foodItem.price }}</div>
```

You're applying `is-static` class when the value of `foodItem.editing` returns `false`. So, in that condition you'll get currency filter applied.

Comment: This affects my edit though, when I press the edit button it will not let me edit the price unlike all other fields?

Comment: No. I don't think so. Why this would affect?

Comment: When I press edit all other fields unlock and I can edit them but this price one will not be editable, just tried it. Not sure why? Probably because it's missing the is-static?

Comment: So, you have `is-static` class on all input fields and you cannot edit on input when there is the class applied?

Comment: I took of my line of code and added what you told me earlier -  `<div v-if="!foodItem.editing">{{ foodItem.price  | currency('£') }}</div>
                                <div v-else>{{ foodItem.price }}</div>
                                <!-- <input v-bind:class="{'is-static': !foodItem.editing}" type="text" class="input" v-model="foodItem.price"> -->`

Comment: Why you commented out your input model?

Comment: My answer is for showing and hiding price div not it's input field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166159/discussion-between-andrew-and-bhojendra-nepal).